# How to sort a datatable and then append rows at the bottom?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a function which is returning the data table. this function appends one extra row that is the calculated sum. Now the requirement has come to sort the data table. I tried to sort the datatable then append the total row, but the data table is also taking the total row in consideration. How can I mitigate this behaviour?

```
          dt.DefaultView.Sort = "totalearning DESC"; //sorting first then adding
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr.ItemArray = new object[] { "Total", dt.Compute("Sum(redeemed)", ""), dt.Compute("Sum(earning)", ""), dt.Compute("Sum(paidhousefee)", ""), dt.Compute("Sum(paidfine)", ""), dt.Compute("Sum(totalearning)", ""), dt.Compute("Sum(noofdayspresent)", ""), dt.Compute("Sum(noofdaysabsent)", ""), dt.Compute("Sum(avgdaily)", "") };
                dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, dt.Rows.Count);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use `Linq-To-DataSet` instead which is more powerful and more readable:

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
     .OrderBy(row => row.Field<string>(0) == "Total")
     .ThenByDescending(row => row.Field<int>("totalearning"))
     .CopyToDataTable();
```

I have presumed that `totalearning` is an `int`-column. Correct it accordingly.

Comment: yes it is working but it is sorting in ascending order, how can i sort it in descending way.

Comment: @Ratna: i have edited my answer, use `ThenByDescending`. Side-note: you can also get the total sum with LINQ if you want: `int total = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r.Field<int>("redeemed"));`